# android `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` interlink with button array

Tags: android, arrays, view, queue

I would like to make a simple game about a boy at the bottom of the screen trying to catch the falling apples. The apples are falling straight down at random x coordinates, and the boy at the bottom can just scroll right or left.

So far the apples now can be generated randomly and correctly animated, and the boy can scroll properly.

However, I am having difficulties in the game core condition: When apple is in the boy's width, the apple is considered successful caught.

### The apples are generated and stored as follows:

```
private final Queue<Button> spots = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Button>();
```

and when generating new apples to the view:

```
spots.add(spot);
```

and when the apples are disappeared from the view:

```
spots.remove(spot);
```

### Checking condition:

I use the below code to check for the condition:
(`BOY_X` is the x-coordinate of the boy)

```
   public void Check_all_Spot(int BOY_X)
   {  
       int [] apple_x;
       int [] apple_y;
       int apple_shown_length =spots.size();
       Button [] apples = null; 

       String text_x ="";
       String text_y = "";

       if (!spots.isEmpty())
       {
           apples = spots.toArray(new Button[apple_shown_length]);
       }

       apple_x =  new int [apple_shown_length];
       apple_y =  new int [apple_shown_length];

       for (int w = 0; w < apple_shown_length ; ++w)
       {
           apple_x[w] = (int) apples[w].getX();
           apple_y[w] = (int) apples[w].getY();            

           text_x = text_x+ "\n" +apple_x[w];
           text_y = text_y+ "\n" +apple_y[w];

           if (     (apple_x[w]+SPOT_DIAMETER)/2 >= BOY_X                           || 
                    (apple_x[w]+SPOT_DIAMETER)/2 <= (BOY_X+BOY_WIDTH)               ||
                    (apple_y[w]+SPOT_DIAMETER)   >= (viewHeight - BOY_HEIGHT)       || 
                    (apple_y[w]+SPOT_DIAMETER)   <= (viewHeight - (BOY_HEIGHT)/2)   )
                    // check text
           {

           }
       }
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "X=" +text_x+"\nY=" +text_y, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

## Question:

In this way of converting the spots queue to a button array `apple`, the toast reports the x and y coordinates for all the apples in the view.

My question is, though now I know about which apple is satisfying the checking condition, how could it be **instructing** to the `spots queue` to **remove** the apple??

Or should I use a game thread and counting the time elasped?

Or I should not convert the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` to button array?

I would like to obtain some of your advice. Many thanks!

Comment: I do not find a direct solution for the above problem, but I have rearranged everything and abandon using ConcurrentLinkedQueue. Instead, I used button array to solve the problem, such that to setId and getID for the buttons inflated and specify the system which one to be removed according to the ID.